# DBus : Can't get match rules for my user's session bus

Tags: dbus, policy, diagnostics

I'm trying to use dbus/tools/GetAllMatchRules.py to get diagnostic information.  When I run it without parameters as my regular user I get "GetConnectionMatchRules failed: did you enable the Stats interface?"

I modified GetAllMatchRules to print the specific exception details.  It now says

GetConnectionMatchRules failed: did you enable the Stats interface?: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: The caller does not have the necessary privileged to call this method

So then I'm wondering, does it work at all? So I sudo su and run it again and it gives me the kind of information I'd expect to see, just not for the right bus.  Oddly, if I use the --system parameter, even root gets org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied .

The repository claims, in bus/example-session-disable-stats.conf.in , that
"If the Stats interface was enabled at compile-time, users can use it on
the session bus by default. Systems providing isolation of processes
with LSMs might want to restrict this. This can be achieved by copying
this file in @EXPANDED_SYSCONFDIR@/dbus-1/session.d/
"

But that's clearly not the case because my user can NOT access this information.

I even tried a brute force approach to disabling (commenting out) ALL deny statements at /usr/share/dbus-1/system.conf and reloading and it still doesn't work.  I also tried a full system restart in case I wasn't reloading correctly.  I also did a system-wide search for system.conf in case it's actually using some other conf file that I'm not seeing, which would mean I'm modifying the wrong thing.  I got a big hint that that's not the case when I had a typo (-- instead of --> for commenting out) and it failed to reload, but did reload once I fixed the typo.

I'm ok with the possibility that I can only do this signed in as root, so I also tried modifying GetAllMatchRules to use dbus.bus.BusConnection(), and force-feeding it the session address (unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus) which results in

"org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken."

Incidentally, this is the same issue that happens if I leave the code alone but use sudo -E su instead of just sudo su (the -E option in this case means that the $DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS variable is retained)

I'm not sure what to try next...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there isn't currently a solution, the privilege error is simply the code that was chosen to indicate that the method is an unimplemented stub method